# Laravel Livewrie Datatables Timeout when loading model

Tags: laravel-livewire

When I setup a datatable, regardless of the object I use, I end up with it attempting to load and eventually timing out. I'm not even sure how to start debugging this.

I've followed some of the examples here: https://livewire-datatables.com/ and simple data tables like:

```html
<livewire:datatable model="App\User" exclude="planet_id, bio, latitude, longitude, updated_at" />
```

Work perfectly. The problem I'm having is when I try anything that requires it's own Datatable class.

My steps/code are as follows:

```
php artisan livewire:make jobs-data-table
```

jobs-data-table.blade.php

```html
<livewire:jobs-data-table searchable="title" exportable />
```

JobsDataTable

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use \App\Models\Job;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\Column;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\DateColumn;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\TimeColumn;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\NumberColumn;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\BooleanColumn;
use Mediconesystems\LivewireDatatables\Http\Livewire\LivewireDatatable;


class JobsDataTable extends Component
{
    public function builder()
    {
        return
            Job::query()->take(10)->get(2);
    }
}
```

Then I setup a simple test route:

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('/livewire/jobs-data-table');
});
```

The route works, but ultimately times out, with no error beyond the timeout exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop - by making the component render itself over and over.

Your route calls the view `livewire/jobs-data-table.blade.php` - and the view calls the `JobsDataTable` component through `<livewire:jobs-data-table ../>`. This will return a new instance of the view, `livewire/jobs-data-table`, which again will initialize the `JobsDataTable` component and continue with that loop until it times out.

Normally, when rendering a full-page Livewire component, you would call the class in the route, not the view directly, that way you render the entire component and not only the view - meaning that using `render()` on any views within the `livewire` folder is bad practice.

```php
Route::get('/test', App\Http\Livewire\JobsDataTable::class);
```

However, doing this will not solve your problem, it wouldn't change anything. You need to render the component *once*.

To solve your problem, you need to render the component in such a way that it doesn't call on itself in the view. That means that your `livewire/jobs-data-table.blade.php` view cannot call `<livewire:jobs-data-table ../>`. Since there's not much more code to show what its doing, being more explicit on what to change exactly is difficult.